# DATE_FORMAT and STR_TO_DATE are not working

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to get the month or day in a date formatted in `05/01/2023 04:33:59 AM` but seems like the two functions are not working. It gives me a `NULL` and `0` results.

This is the scripts that I've tried. I have combined the queries for the sample.

```
SELECT 
     format1.date1, format2.date2 
FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%d') AS date1 FROM may2023) format1, 
      (SELECT DAY(STR_TO_DATE(datetime, "%Y")) AS date2 FROM `may2023`) format2
```

Any advice and help for this one? Thanks in advance.

Comment: show sample data and wanted result, that query makes so not much sense

Comment: You have no `WHERE` conditions in your subqueries. When a subquery is used as an expression it has to return just one row and column.

Comment: are you saying you have a date stored in a string column in the format you show and you want to get the month and day of month from it?  str_to_date has to be passed the format for the entire string you are trying to convert to a date.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did it wrong. I have put the ```str_to_date ()``` function inside the ```date_format()``` and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like that?

```
CREATE TABLE may2023 (
  datetime VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO may2023 (datetime)
VALUES ('05/01/2023 04:33:59 AM');

SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(datetime, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'), '%m') AS month,
  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(datetime, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'), '%d') AS day
FROM may2023;
```